# Visual Studio Code incorrect Running Command

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

When running my code Visual Studio Code runs the below commands that DO NOT INCLUDE the C++17 standard.

```
[Running] cd "/Users/charlesclark/Desktop/projects/helloworld/" && g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld && "/Users/charlesclark/Desktop/projects/helloworld/"helloworld
```

PROBLEM: I am operating on an M1 MacBook Pro and need to run the below command but in Visual Studio Code:

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % clang++ -std=c++17 helloworld.cpp
```

What I have tried so far is creating a c_cpp_properties.json file with the following settings:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
    }
],
"version": 4}
```

And a tasks.json file with the following settings:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
  {
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "clang++ build active file",
    "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
    "args": [
      "-std=c++17",
      "-stdlib=libc++",
      "-g",
      "${file}",
      "-o",
      "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    ],
    "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  }
]}
```

TO REPRODUCE THIS PROBLEM: Follow the instructions in the link below using an M1 MacBook Pro. You will begin having issues at "Start a debugging session".
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

Comment: Does not look like its using your tasks.json at all. Is this file in the .vscode folder?

Comment: Yes, it is in the .vscode folder. And I agree, I do not think it is using the tasks.json file either.